# How do you extract the first column of the selected row in DataTables?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I want to extract the first column of the DataTables when clicked.

This is my DataTable Code, sourced from my SQL DB

```
<tbody>
  <form action="index.php   " method="POST">
    <?php
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($showMemo))
      {
          echo'
            <tr>
                <td>'. $row["employee_id"]     .'</td>
                <td>'. $row["employee_name"]   .'</td>
                <td>'. $row["employee_number"] .'</td>
                <td>'. $row["employee_status"] .'</td>
                <td>'. 
                   <a href="..." id="edit" >Activate Employee</a> .' 
                </td>
            </tr>
              ';
      }
    ?>
  </form>
```

Lets break it down: 
Employee ID: Primary key from my 'employees' table

Employee Name: Name of Employee

 Employee Number: Number of Employee

Employee Status: [Active] or [Not Active]

Activate Employee Link: [1] for Activate employee [0] Deactivate employee
Im having a hard time adding getting the first column (employee_id) which will be referenced for the row to be updated.

This is my jQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
                "order": [[ 6, 'asc' ]]});
    } );
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean saving in a variable a reference to the first column of the table when clicking... where?

Comment: Maybe $('#myTable td').eq(0)

Comment: I mean, when the link is click, the 'employee_id' will be used during the update query on the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it by reference.

First, you should not define a fixed id in a loop (they should be unique):

Change this:

```
<a href="..." id="edit" >Activate Employee</a> .'
```

To this:

```
 <a href="..." class="edit" >Activate Employee</a> .'
```

And then this should get you the id:

```
$('.edit').click(function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault(); // Avoid the href to be followed by the browser

   // get the contents of the first td in the closest tr 
   var id = $('td:first-child', $(this).closest('tr')).html();

   // Just continue with your ajax request...
});
```

Comment: Your a lifesaver <3 Thank you Dionei.

Comment: I was wondering, how can you pass the 'id' to the php query on the update clause?